# Amend a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

So I have a CSV file with a bunch on IP's in it:

```
192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3,192.168.0.4,192.168.0.5,192.168.0.6,192.168.0.7,192.168.0.8,192.168.0.9,192.168.0.10
```

And I would like to add a new ip to the end of this csv file. Currently I am using this code to read in the data:

```
requests = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
for request in requests:
    for ip in request:
        print "In List: " + str(ip)
```

This will print:

```
In List: 192.168.0.1
In List: 192.168.0.2
In List: 192.168.0.3
In List: 192.168.0.4
In List: 192.168.0.5
...
```

And then to write one to the end I've tried many methods, including this:

```
requestWriter = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
requestWriter.writerow(["192.168.0.X"])
```

This however replaces the whole file with the new entry. I then tried to loop through existing records and add them to the new file but this split the IP's up by their .'s! Am I missing something here? Surely there is an amend option for the csv reader/writer?

Thanks

Comment: You are not developing in Windows, isn't it? Because "rb" means read+binary and csv is tipically not binary. This probably works because you are developing on a system that does not differentiate between binary and text files (ie b has no effect).

Comment: "and csv is typically not binary".  Since for Windows it **is** binary, it's simpler to open CSV with "wb" to assure compatibility.

Comment: @S.Lott uh, csv is binary in Windows?

Comment: @systempuntoout: In an obscure way, yes. From http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer.   "If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference."  And the platform where it makes a difference is?  You guessed it.  Windows.

Comment: -1: "I can't really disclose what system I'm working on".  Can't possibly be true unless it was a seekrit custom-built operating system where disclosure of status as the only client would somehow violate national security.  Otherwise, it's difficult to be **sure** of an answer when there's this kind of refusal to disclose basic facts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you just append a new row?

```
fd = open('file.csv','a')
fd.write(yourCsvRowWithNewIP)
fd.close()
```

Comment: @ing0: You can still use the CSV writer; the important part is opening the file with mode `'a'`. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @systempuntoout: Don't forget the comma!

Comment: @aaron It's ok, I didn't forget! :)